# Can't pull data from a stubborn webpage using vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Hope you are doing well. The site i tried to scrape category-names from is very simple to look at if you notice it's inspected element but when i create a parser i can't pull the data. I wanted to scrape only the 7 category names from that page. I tried with all possible angles but failed. If anybody helps me point out what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful to him. Thanks in advance. FYC, I'm pasting here the code I tried with.

```
Sub ItemName()

Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics As Object, topic As Object, posts As Object, post As Object, ele As Object
Dim x As Long

x = 2

http.Open "GET", "http://www.bjs.com/tv--electronics.category.3000000000000144985.2002193", False
http.send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("categories")

For Each topic In topics
    For Each posts In topic.getElementsByTagName("li")
        For Each post In posts.getElementsByTagName("a")
            Set ele = post.getElementsByTagName("h4")(0)
            Cells(x, 1) = ele.innerText
            x = x + 1
        Next post
    Next posts
Next topic

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not initially grabbing the full page.  If you step through the code, it's pulling some form of mobile menu.  I tried changing the request header, "user-agent", but it still pulls that info.  [I wonder if you'd have better luck with the browser control, versus MSXMLHttp](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the content of that site are generated dynamically, so there is no way for xmlhttp request to catch the page source. However, to get around that selenium is good to go, as it works well when it comes to deal with javascriptheavy website. I only used selenium in my below script to get the page source. As soon as it get that, I reverted back to usual vba method to accomplish the process.

```
Sub Grabbing_item()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With driver
        .get "http://www.bjs.com/tv--electronics.category.3000000000000144985.2002193"
        html.body.innerHTML = .ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML;")
        .Quit
    End With

    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("name")
        x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = post.innerText
    Next post
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution, I'm using the internet explorer object instead of MSXML. I'm able to retrieve the data from the page, and it's pretty quick.

Here's the full code:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub ItemName()
On Error GoTo errhand:
    Dim ie As Object: Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim topics As Object, topic As Object
    Dim i As Byte

    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "http://www.bjs.com/tv--electronics.category.3000000000000144985.2002193"
        Sleep 500 ' Wait for the page to start loading
        Do Until .document.readyState = 4 Or .busy = False Or i >= 100
            Sleep 100
            DoEvents
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With

    Set topics = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("name ng-binding")

    For Each topic In topics
        'Print out the element's innertext
        Debug.Print topic.innertext
    Next

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Exit Sub

errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your sweet effort. I try to avoid IE because it slows my computer down. Btw, i have already found what i was missing that is: the class name in my code should be "brick" and after slight modification of my code it is working. Thanks.